# Force 1080i video at 59.94fps

Tags: hdmi, display, video

I'm trying to set up a Raspberry pi to output video to an ancient TV transmitter which requires HD interlaced video at 59.94fps.

The Pi HDMI output is connected to a BlackMagic micro HDMI to SDI converter, which reports many supported formats, so auto-detection doesn't work.  I believe I need to force the correct video output, probably with something in config.txt.

I can temporarily enable the correct output format with this command:

```
tvservice -e "CEA 5 HDMI" --ntsc
```

I can save the `CEA 5 HDMI` part to `/boot/config.txt` like this:

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=5
```

But when I reboot I get 60fps output, not 59.94fps.

How can I force 59.94fps?

Comment: see https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/ and https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

Comment: sorry, there's no way to boot into that "mode" - as far as I can tell, `tvservice -e "CEA 5 HDMI" --ntsc` is the only way to do it - put that in rc.local script?

Comment: unless ... `hdmi_cvt=1920 1080 59.94 3 0 1 \n
hdmi_group=2 \n
hdmi_mode=87 \n
hdmi_drive=2`

Comment: @JaromandaX Unfortunately the `hdmi_cvt` statement is ignored if the frame rate includes decimal points.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no way to set this mode in `/boot/config.txt`.

What worked for me was to follow @JaromandaX's suggestion and put the `tvservice -e "CEA 5 HDMI" --ntsc` command in `/etc/rc.local`.